# Python "header.py" module

Tags: python, django, python-import, python-module

I've split one large python file containing a bunch of methods into several smaller ones. However, there's one problem: I'd like all of these small files to import almost the same modules.

I've tried to create a `header.py` file where I just pasted the common header. I've then added `from header import *` on the other ones, but it seems to me that this would only import the *methods* listed on `header.py`, rather than the *actual modules*.

I know one solution is to figure out which libraries each small file depends on, but isn't there a faster way to do that?

Comment: IMHO this is rather bad practice. You could do what @aIKid suggests, but you should strive for importing only what you need in the module. This is not C where you have a common prototype (header) file :)

Comment: Sure, I imagined this wouldn't be an elegant solution, as I couldn't find any documentation supporting this solution anywhere. I guess I'll import just what's needed in every module. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very important and useful to have all dependencies in a .py file to be listed in the import statements. That way we can easily trace back the source of all modules used.

Say if you are using `module1.method` somewhere and want to check where this `method` came from, you'll always find in the import statements at the top. This is the reason why `from module1 import *` is highly discouraged.

We can do what you need in neat way.

In your header.py

```
import module1
import module2
```

In your other files,

```
import header

header.module1.method() #make all the function calls via header module.
```

If you think its making your code writing tedious because of longer function names, then may be try this.

```
import header as h
h.module1.method()
```

But please make sure you don't have untraceable modules in your python files.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid rewriting the smaller modules, but I guess this is inevitable. Thanks for the elegant solution :)